# Getting a specific post values to another div or modal

Tags: php, posts, html

So I was trying to loop all the post from wordpress with the_excerpt. Then I was stuck on how to get and pass the data from a single post by clicking a link or button to appear the_content() on a modal div.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <p><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
    <div class="blog-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
 </div> 
 <?php endwhile; else : ?>
 <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
```

this is how my modal look like..

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <!-- the_content() in here-->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

not sure this will work

```
<button class="btn btn-primary tag_cnt" onclick="showModal('data')" type="button" value="<?php $post->post_content;?>"></button>
```

then use a function like this

```
function showModal(data)
{

   $("#myModal .modal-body").html(data)
   $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

but how do i transfer multiple values like the_content and the_title?

Comment: what is the JavaScript code that you use to display the modal ? is it jQuery UI ? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: using a bootstrap, was thinking on putting the value on a button like this..<button class="btn btn-primary tag_cnt" style="top:144px; left:510px" onclick="showModal('data')" type="button" value="<?php $post->post_content?>"></button>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways:

## Json Encode

This is my favorite way of passing data/settings/etc to the front-end.

### PHP

```
$obj=array(
    'content' => $post->post_content,
    'title' => esc_html( get_the_title() )
);
```

Now the button output will be like this:

### HTML

```
<button class='btn btn-primary tag_cnt get_button_more_info' type='button' value='<?=json_encode($obj)?>'></button>
```

### Javascript

```
(function($) {

  $('.get_button_more_info').on('click',function() {
    var obj = $(this).val();
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    $("#myModal .modal-body").html(obj.content)
    $("#myModal .modal-title").html(obj.title)
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: sweet!, looks good, gotta try this when I got home.

Comment: Yes, the php works great however for some reasons the script is not. Am i missing a librabry using this script?

Comment: Only jQuery it needs. In the console will show the error.

Comment: There is an unexpected error end of json input JSON.parse

Comment: This means that the obj isn't a Json string. Is the value of button content a valid Json?

Comment: Looks like this...... value="{"content":"some content","title":"a title"}"</button> ==$0

Comment: I have updated my Answer `<button class='btn btn-primary tag_cnt get_button_more_info' type='button' value='<?=json_encode($obj)?>'></button>`. So the double quotes don't interfere with the `JSON.parse`

Comment: Perfect! You saved me. Trying to learn. Will defintely used this technique in the future. GOOD answer man!

Comment: By the way, indentions on the content seems to be broken. Format is probably different using a json string

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Nvm, have to split /n and join the br tag since it uses the html format. Got it now thanks for the reply